How to debug unreliable middle-button copy/paste (selection does not always update)
I used to love the select text -> paste immediately with middle button. But recently it has become very buggy for me:

pasting seems to work a bit, then holds onto an old selection, and continues to paste this what the most recent selection is
the paste buffers differ from middle-click and shift+insert, sometimes. For example, in this text window (firefox) they have diverged. Also  But for selections/pastes wholly inside gnome-terminal, the two remain consistent.

I've read Q&As on disabling the middle button paste, on enabling it in xterm, some xinput hardware setup for X11, and what seem like rabbit holes about xclip.  Nothing I've seen seems to report the lack of reliability problem that I've got.
Question: How can I debug this?  What tools show a) the contents of these buffers and b) when they change? I don't know how to determine whether it is a writing issue or a reading issue for example, nor which buffers are being used, or even how many there are.
I'm using fedora 40, kernel 6.9.6, with gnome 46 + wayland.

I've also seen issues like this. Without doing any research or testing, I believe some application is holding onto the selection buffer and isn't allowing other applications to select data.  If you find the offending application and kill/restart it, sometimes the problem goes away.  Next time I see this happen, maybe I'll investigate and try to come up with a better answer.
